# Why would you set the reset at the input state of FSM to 1?

Tags: microcontroller, sequential-logic

I am trying to find the answers online but without any luck. The FSM is a moore machine and there is a reset that is set to 1. What is the function of a reset? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To bring the machine to a known state.  Without a reset, on power-up the internal state of the machine would be random.

So your "save the world" state machine, which should come up in the "check if all is well" state may come up in "nuke the commies" state, and start world-war III just because of an easily-avoided design flaw.

Answer (score 1):

A reset takes a the flip-flops or latches of a digital logic circuit to known initial values, before the circuit starts performing its functions.

A common reason for needing a reset is for correct operation after power-up. During power-up, the supply rails will rise from 0 V to their steady operating levels, any clock oscillators will start up and produce stable frequencies, any PLLs will lock and so on. During that time, the circuit can be held in reset and only released from reset when all this hardware is settled and working. Often, this is done by a circuit that just waits much longer than this settling time, holding the circuit in reset while it waits.

If the circuit tried to operate without a reset, a circuit's flip-flops/latches may well contain random or unwanted logic values and the circuit sets off in the wrong direction.

Power-on resets are not the only resets but they show the problem and its solution.

FSMs must (nearly always) start in a predictable and known state so a reset is used. And that's why your FSM has one.